# Light node - setup an configuration

Tags: go-ethereum, prysm, lighthouse, nethermind

I am stacked with proper approach for deploying light node.
Could some one tell me which combination clients (execution layer + consensus layer) do I need to use it for deploy light node on my computer for developer purpose (pos).
What setting do i need to set?

Main goals:
0)I want to have quick sync time
1)I want to have access to txpool(mempool) - to see my tx.
2)I want to interact with my contracts.
3)Low ssd wear of.

Currently i use mac os with ssd but after development I will buy or rent separate machine.

Tiny additional question...
How much will the SSD drive wear out with irregular startup for testing network access - 20-40 hours per week. Will this harm the internal SSD of the MacBook? Or better use external ssd?

What capacity of SSD do i need for light node?

Thank you!

Did a lot investigate but dint find answers
Run geth + prysm - but it doesnt have light mode
Run sepolia